# Use test-kitchen with Vagrant and Parallels?

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, parallels, test-kitchen

Is it possible to use test-kitchen with Vagrant and Parallels?

I have a working kitchen using Virtualbox, but I wanted to try with Parallels. I've installed the [Vagrant Parallels plugin](https://github.com/Parallels/vagrant-parallels) and confirmed that is working. But when I run `kitchen converge`, it is still using Virtualbox. My .kitchen.yml has:

```
driver:
  name: vagrant
```

This documentation seems to imply that Parallels is not supported by kitchen-vagrant?

*"The kitchen-vagrant driver for Kitchen generates a single Vagrantfile for each instance of Kitchen in a sandboxed directory. The kitchen-vagrant driver supports VirtualBox and VMware Fusion, requires Vagrant 1.1.0 (or higher), and is the default driver for Kitchen."*

https://docs.chef.io/config_yml_kitchen.html

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a VM on Parallels with these options in .kitchen.yml:

```
platforms:
  - name: debian8
    driver:
      box: parallels/debian-8.3
      provider: parallels
```